# Error de sintaxis inválida

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy empezando a programar y he estado probando este código:

```
from tkinter import *

def ingresar():
    Total+=Cantidad

def retirar():
    Total-=Cantidad

ventana=Tk()
Total=IntVar()
Cantidad=IntVar()
ventana.title("Banco")
ventana.geometry("400x400")
etiqueta=Label(ventana,text="Introduzca una cifra").place(x=30,y=160)
Cantidadcaja=Entry(ventana,textvariable=Cantidad).place(x=200,y=160)
boton=Button(ventana,text="Ingresar",command=ingresar).place(x=200,y=210)
boton2=Button(ventana,text="Retirar",command=retirar).place(x=270,y=210)
etiqueta1=Label(ventana,text=("En su cuenta hay "),Total,("euros").place(x=300,y=200)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Me salta este error:

> ```
> File "bancoTK.py", line 18    
>     ventana.mainloop()    
>           ^    
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: Podrias aclarar cual es la linea 18...

Comment: la linea 18 es la ultima la de ventana.mainloop()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Además del error tipográfico, comentado por Carlos, sobre los paréntesis en la línea anterior a la marcada por el error, que debería quedar así (aunque esto solo soluciona el error de sintaxis):

```
etiqueta1=Label(ventana, text=("En su cuenta hay ", Total, "euros")).place(x=300,y=200)
```

hay otros errores importantes a tener en cuenta:

1. No puedes definir las funciones antes de definir las variables globales que usas en ellas, a no ser que se las pases como argumentos.
2. No puedes definir el texto del label como si se tratara de una llamada a la función `print`, deberias proporcionarle una cadena al argumento `text`. Para ello usa formato de cadenas, preferiblemente usando el método `str.format()`, aunque también puedes concatenar previo casting a `str`.
3. No puedes operar con variables de Tkinter como si fueran variables de Python, no puedes hacer `Total-=Cantidad`. Debes usar los métodos `set` (para asignar un valor a la variable) y `get` (para obtener el valor asignado a la variable).
4. Para que el label se actualize de forma automática al cambiar la varible `Total` tienes que usar el argumento `textvariable`. No obstante, esto te impide personalizar el texto. Tienes varias opciones, una de ellas es usar el método`trace` de tu variable `Total` de forma que cuando cambie su valor llame a una función para que actualize el texto del label de fórma automática.

   Para ver más información sobre las variables de Tkinter mírate: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm
5. No debes usar el método `place` o `grid` sobre la misma línea donde defines el widget:

   ```
   label = tk.Label(text= 'Hola').place(0, 0)
   ```

   Esto ocasiona que la variable `label` sea la salida del método `place`, es decir, `None`. Si necesitas usar el nombre `label` para referenciar tu widget posteriormente no podreás hacerlo. Por esto, o separas las líneas, si vas a usar el nombre a posteriori:

   ```
   label = tk.Label(text= 'Hola')
   label.place(0, 0)
   ```

   O si no vas a hacer referencia nunca a tu widget, entoces no crees una variable que no va a ser usada, haz simplemente:

   ```
    tk.Label(text= 'Hola').place(0, 0)
   ```

Además de lo anterior, y dado que estas aprendiendo, unas cuantas consideraciones:

1. No debes importar usando la forma `from módulo import *` en Python, está considerada una mala práctica, por mucho que los de Effbot no se dignen a actualizar la documentación :(. Dado que estas aprendiendo, es bueno no adquirir estas prácticas. Hay tres razones básicas:

   - Primero, es inseguro y confuso en códigos complejos o extensos, se puede terminar sobreescribiendo un método o variable sin querer, ocasionando errores o resultados inesperados difíciles de encontrar.
   - Es muy ineficiente con la memoria.
   - Dificulta la legibilidad del código al no saber el namespace al que pertenece la clase/función/variable. Esto es muy importante para la filosofía de Python: "Explícito mejor que implícito".

     Usa `import tkinter` o para ahorrar letras al escribir, se suele utilizar por convención `import tkinter as tk`.
2. Los nombres que empiezan con mayúscula se suelen reservar para nombrar clases.

Tu código quedaría si:

```
import tkinter as tk


ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Banco")
ventana.geometry("400x400")
total = tk.IntVar(ventana)
cantidad = tk.IntVar(ventana)    

def ingresar():
    total.set(total.get() + cantidad.get())

def retirar():
    total.set(total.get() - cantidad.get())

def actualizar_label(*args):
    etiqueta1.configure(text = "En su cuenta hay {} euros.".format(total.get()))

total.trace("w", actualizar_label)


etiqueta = tk.Label(ventana,text="Introduzca una cifra")
etiqueta.place(x=30, y=160)

cantidad_caja = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=cantidad)
cantidad_caja.place(x=200, y=160)

boton = tk.Button(ventana, text="Ingresar", command=ingresar)
boton.place(x=200, y=210)

boton2 = tk.Button(ventana, text="Retirar", command=retirar)
boton2.place(x=270, y=210)

etiqueta1 = tk.Label(ventana, text="En su cuenta hay {} euros.".format(total.get()))
etiqueta1.place(x=200, y=185)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchísimo más completa que mi solución.

Comment: FJSevilla, hay una errata en `import tkinter from tk` antes del segundo punto 2. Y tienes toda la razón: la manera correcta de dar formato a una cadena es con `format` y no concatenando valores convertidos a `str`. Gran explicación, he aprendido mucho.

Comment: Muchas gracias @CarlosA.Gómez, tienes toda la razón, corregido. Para cosas como esta o para faltas ortográficas, que no son raras en mi... :(, siente libre de editar la respuesta.  En cuanto a lo del formato, la verdad es que no es que exista la forma correcta, lo que ocurre es que `format` o los [literales de cadena formateados](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) de Python 3.6 son más legibles y flexibles que el viejo método de c usando `%`, que se intenta dejar de lado, aunque sigue siendo válido. Saludos.

Comment: Genial. Sí, eso había leído, que se intentaba dejar atrás el método de `%` que imitaba a *C*. Aprendo mucho con tus respuestas y comentarios. Python es un lenguaje increíble.

Comment: muchas gracias a los 2 por vuestra ayuda

Comment: @Snake de nada, para eso estamos. Ya que eres nuevo por [es.so] te recomiendo mirarte [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Por otro lado, cuando crees nuevas preguntas, esperamos que sigas por aquí...:), recuerda formatear el código adecuadamente, lo seleccionas y pulsas el botón `{}` del editor o `Ctrl + k`. Siempre es importante, pero en Python dado que usa la identación para definir los bloques de código, es esencial. Saludos.

Comment: porque ahora me lanza este error  File "banco.py", line 13
    total.set(total.get() + cantidad.get())
                                          ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation                   al intentar escribir esto:                                                                        def ingresar():
     total.set(total.get() + cantidad.get())

Comment: @Snake estas mezclando tabulaciones con espacios en la identación de un mismo bloque. Por norma general no debes usar tabulaciones para identar, PEP 8 establece que se idente cada nivel usando cuatro espacios. Generalmente los IDEs tabulan con espacios si están bién configurados. Yo uso 4 espacios siempre, en tu caso si eso es todo lo añadido identa la línea  `total.set(total.get() + cantidad.get())` con cuatro espacios delante, aunque tu IDE deberia estar configurado para identar con cuatro espacios aunque uses la tecla Tab.

Comment: me sigue lanzando el mismo error

Comment: @Snake en algún lado estas usando tabulaciones, el error es muy claro ¿Que editor/ide estas usando?

Comment: Utilizo Sublime Text 3

Comment: @Snake vete a `View` >> `Identation` >> `Convert Identation to Spaces`. Asegurate de tener en ese mismo menu marcadas las opciones `Indent Using Spaces` y debajo `Tab Width: 4`. Esto deberia corregir hacer congruente la identación.

Comment: es verdad me habia confundido tienes razon sobre tu respuesta

Comment: e creado una ventana y se me congela en esta parte del codigo              `def comprobar():
 while True:
  if usuario.get()=("juan") and contraseña.get()==(123) or usuario.get()==("mara") and contraseña.get()==("2402"):
   if usuario.get()==("juan") and contraseña.get()==(123):
    print("Bienvenido Juan")
    ventana2()
   if usuario.get()==("juan") and contraseña.get()==("2402"):
    print("Bienvenida Mara")
    ventana2()
   else:
    print("El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos")
    return ventana` no se si e creado un bucle infinito sin querer

Comment: @Snake no puedes usar ciclos bloqueantes en GUIs, el `While True` bloquea el `mainloop()` y la interfaz se bloquea al no poder redibujarse y responder a eventos. Mirate esta pregunta del sitio en inglés :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131486/tkinter-root-mainloop-with-while-true-loop . Si tienes problemas crea una nueva pregunta explicando el problema y aportando el código  y vemos que se puede hacer. No debemos usar los comentarios para conversaciones extendidas y aún no tienes reputación para usar el chat. Saludos.

Comment: mi ultima pregunta por los comentarios, si no puedo usar while true que puedo usar

Comment: @Snake Una alternativa es usar lo que la respuesta a la pregunta que te doy arriba sugiere: usar el método [after](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) de forma que cada x tiempo se llame a una función que hace las comprobaciones que tu haces en el While. No obstante, si estas validando usuario y contraseña ¿Por qúe no usas un botón para aceptar los datos en vez de estar continuamente validando? Si lo estas usando el While no hace falta para nada. Si realmente no sabes por donde tirar te aconsejo crear otra pregunta explicando que hace y que debería hacer tu GU