# ¿Cómo mostrar una imágen distinta en cada ejecución de mi interfaz mediante persistencia de datos?

Tags: python, hilos, tkinter, serialización

Estoy intentando crear una aplicación con Tkinter que me permita mostrar una imágen distinta (de un conjunto definido en una lista) cada vez que es ejecutado.

El programa debe hacer lo siguiente:

1. Mostrar un splash screen que debe contener una imagen (introductoria no pertenece a la lista) que se muestra durante un tiempo determinado y luego se cierra.
2. Cuando el splash se cierra se debe abrir la aplicación principal que muestra otra imágen (esta es la que debe cambiar en cada ejecución), se muestra durante otro tiempo determinado y se cierra.

Este ciclo se repite, de forma que la imágen mostrada en la aplicación principal va rotando de acuerdo al orden definido en la lista de imágenes. El problema es que necesito guardar de alguna forma la imágen usada por el script para que en la siguiente ejecución continue con la siguiente de la lista. Lo estoy intentando con `pickle` pero no lo consigo.

Este es mi código:

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
from datetime import *
import time
import random
import os       
import threading
import sched
from sched import *
import pickle
hora1=15
hora2=21
hora3=16
fichero = open("Imagen.txt", "w")
obj=-1
pickle.dump(obj, fichero)
fichero.close()
fichero=open("Imagen.txt","r")
obj=pickle.load(fichero)
class SplashScreen(Frame):
     def __init__(self, master=None, useFactor=True):
            Frame.__init__(self, master)
            self.master.geometry("1366x768+0+0")
            self.master.config(bg="black")
            self.master.overrideredirect(True)
            self.lift()
def p():
     root = Tk()
     sp = SplashScreen(root)
     sp.config(bg="black")
     fichero.close()
     Img1=PhotoImage(file="Libre.gif")
     Img2=PhotoImage(file="Soy.gif")
     Img3=PhotoImage(file="universe.gif")
     Img4=PhotoImage(file="BBN.gif")
     Img5=PhotoImage(file="tr.gif")
     Img6=PhotoImage(file="final.gif")
     Img7=PhotoImage(file="alc.gif")
     Img8=PhotoImage(file="cer.gif")
     Img9=PhotoImage(file="at.gif")
     Img10=PhotoImage(file="bos.gif")
     Img11=PhotoImage(file="se.gif")
     #Img=PhotoImage(file=".gif")
     Imagenes=[Img1,Img2,Img3,Img4,Img5,Img7,Img8,Img9,Img10,Img11]
     Imgf=obj
     Imagenf=Imagenes[Imgf]
     #logo=Label(root,image=Img6).place(x=00,y=00)
     lbl=Label(root,image=Imagenf).place(x=00,y=00)
     #lbl2=Label(root,image=Img10).place(x=00,y=00)
     root.after(20000,root.destroy)
     root.mainloop()
def t():
     root = Tk()
     sp = SplashScreen(root)
     sp.config(bg="black")
     Img6=PhotoImage(file="final.gif")
     logo=Label(root,image=Img6).place(x=00,y=00)
     root.after(2000,root.destroy)
     root.mainloop()
p=threading.Thread(target=p)
t=threading.Thread(target=t)
if (hora3 == datetime.now().hour) or ((datetime.now().hour == hora2) or(datetime.now().hour == hora1)):
     p.start()
     t.start()
```

Con lo que no consigo que el índice aumente entre ejecuciones.

Comment: ger como te comente anteriormente debes explicar que debe hacer tu aplicación de forma detallada. Esto es tan importante como el código, nosotros no podemos saber que es lo que tienes en mente. Parace que tratas de lanzar una aplicación con un SplashScreen, ¿cual es el flujo de la app? Se lanza la app y sale el splash mientras la ventana principal se oculta, ambos salen a la vez y luego desaparece el splash, etc. ¿Porque instancias el splash en un hilo diferente y tambien en p? Si es un simple splash no debes usar hilos sino toplevel(), los hilos hay que manejarlos con cuidado y más en GUIs.

Comment: Solucionar lo de la imagen no es complicado pero primero hay que aclarar el uso de los hilos, no es trivial pasar variables entre hilo como haces tu con el fichero abierto. Por eso es muy importante que expliques el funcionamiento que deberia tener la app.  Por otro lado, cuando se llegue a la última imágen ¿se empieza de nuevo por la primera?

Comment: Ok pues básicamente no se muchos sobre threads o hilos se que son para hacer procesos múltiples pero no se usarlos bien porque nunca se me había presentado usarlos así que gracias por tu corrección con respecto al flujo del programa es: el splashscreen debe contener una imagen (introductoria no pertenece a la lista)>la imagen debe morir>entra otra imagen(que pertenece a la lista)>la imagen muere>muere el programa y pues cada vez la siguiente imagen debe ser distinta

Comment: si se empieza de nuevo con la primera otra cosa era que a tu forma de ver es mejor un random sin repetición o así como lo intento hacer en orden y después repite y repite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero de todo, para hacer un Splash puedes recurrir a hilos, en algunos casos en los que se hacen ciertas tareas pesadas en el hilo principal mientras se muestra el splash, son necesarios. No obstante, en tu caso, puedes prescindir de ellos y recurrir al método `Toplevel` para crear una ventana secundaria.

Puedes recurrir al método `withdraw` para ocultar la ventana mientras se muestra el Splash y posteriormente muestras de nuevo la ventana principal con `deiconify`.

No es necesario que cargues todas las imágenes, carga solo la que muestres en esa ejecución.

Tu gran problema se encontraba en como almacenar el índice para posteriores ejecuciones. La idea es simple:

- Primero el programa mira si existe el archivo o no. Si no existe asume el índice 0.
- Si existe obtine el índice lo obtiene y le suma uno.
- Finalmente guarda el índice en el archivo para la próxima ejecución.

Todo esto se soluciona de forma simple mediante un bloque `try-except-finally`, aunque se puede hacer de otras formas.

El código queda así:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import pickle

class SplashScreen(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.geometry("1366x768+0+0")
        self.config(bg="black")
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.Img6=tk.PhotoImage(file="final.gif")
        tk.Label(self, image=self.Img6).place(x=00,y=00)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("1366x768+0+0")
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.withdraw()
        self.splash = SplashScreen(self)
        self.after(2000, self.salir_splash)
        self.indice = 0
        self.imagenes = ("Libre.gif", "Soy.gif", "universe.gif", "BBN.gif", "tr.gif" ,"final.gif","alc.gif",
                         "cer.gif", "at.gif", "bos.gif", "se.gif", "Libre.gif", "Soy.gif","universe.gif",
                         "BBN.gif", "tr.gif", "alc.gif", "cer.gif", "at.gif", "bos.gif", "se.gif")


        self.cargar_datos()
        self.Imagenf = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.imagenes[self.indice])
        tk.Label(self, image=self.Imagenf).place(x=00,y=00)
        self.after(20000, self.destroy)


    def salir_splash(self):
        self.splash.destroy()
        self.deiconify()

    def cargar_datos(self):
        try:
            with open("Imagen.dat", "rb") as f:
                self.indice = (pickle.load(f) + 1) % len(self.imagenes) 
        except: pass
        finally:
            with open("Imagen.dat", "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(self.indice, f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

He eliminado la parte de las horas, pero puedes añadir el condicional en el bloque del `if __name__ == "__main__"` perfectamente. No se si este módulo lo llamas desde otro importandolo o como lo usas exactamente, si tienes algún problema con esto coméntalo.

He eliminado el `from Tkinter import *`, esto en Python es una mala práctica y debe evitarse. Lo comento en todas las respuestas sobre Tkinter porque es muy común ya que Effbot (sitio de referencia para Tkinter en cuanto a documentación) usa esta forma a pesar de ser una mala práctica y estar marcado así en los PEPs. Para no repetir lo mismo, puedes mirarte esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/85791/15089) donde explico esto.

Las imágenes se van mostrando una cada vez que se ejecuta el script y al llegar a la última empieza de nuevo. De esto se encarga el operador módulo (%) en `(pickle.load(f) + 1) % len(self.imagenes)`. De esta forma siempre mantenemos el índice dentro de los límites de la lista.

Comment: @ger el código está probado en Python 2.7 y Python 3.6 (cambiando `import Tkinter as tk` por `import tkinter as tk`) usando imágenes propias. Si tienes cualquier duda o problema solo comentalo. Saludos.

Comment: ok gracias lo revise un par de veces pero tuve que colocar como comentario esto para ejecutar el script self.imagenes = ['1.gif', '2.gif', '3.gif', '4.gif'] y funcionó bien este fragmento sirve como ejemplo para remplazar los numeros por nombres de archivos reales o tiene alguna función

Comment: @ger perdona, ya edite la respuesta corrigiendo eso, quitalo. Eso era la lista de imágenes mias con las que hice la prueba. Al copiar el código no las borré y cuando me di cuenta edite para quitarlo. Fuiste más rápido que yo...XD

Comment: me dice TclError: couldn't open "3.gif": no such file or directory y así con cada una de la lista

Comment: jajaja ok gracias nuevamente otra vez fuiste muy acertado con tu respuesta

Comment: @ger una cosa, supongo que te habrás dado cuenta. He editado tu pregunta agregando a mi manera la información que diste en los comentarios. Como te comenté, los comentarios no tienen garantía de persistencia, pueden ser eliminados por lo que la pregunta queda falta de información importante para otros usuarios que pueden beneficiarse de ella y de sus respuestas. Además, los comentarios no aparecer en las búsquedas. De todas formas, la pregunta es tuya, si quieres modificar algo, agregar algo o no estas conforme con algo, puedes deshacer o agregar lo que quieras. Saludos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61905/discussion-between-ger-and-fjsevilla).