# Fichero generado con py2exe falla al ejecutar

Tags: python, cmd, exe

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
''' Archivo: setup.py '''
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from distutils.core import setup 
import py2exe 

setup(name="Ejemplo", 
 version="1.0", 

 author="autor", 
 author_email="email del autor", 
 url="url del proyecto", 

 scripts=["Imagen2.py"], 
 console=["Imagen2.py"], 
 options={"py2exe": {"bundle_files": 1}}, 
 zipfile=None,
)
```

Estoy intentando crear un ejecutable utilizando **py2exe** con el siguiente comando:

```
C:directorio/ubicación/del/script>py2exe setup.py
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el fichero, obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Este es un enlace al programa con el que estoy trabajando:

[¿Cómo mostrar una imágen distinta en cada ejecución de mi interfaz mediante persistencia de datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85821/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-una-im%c3%a1gen-distinta-en-cada-ejecuci%c3%b3n-de-mi-interfaz-mediante-pers)

Comment: Es difícil saber el problema sin ver código. El *setup.py* no es suficiente. ¿Qué dependencias tienes? Normalmente, pyinstaller está más actualizado y más en línea con dependencias complejas como PyQT, scipy,... (código compilado). Explica un poco más sobre lo que quieres hacer e igual encontramos una solución.

Comment: Parece que no es capaz de encontrar los ficheros de imágenes. Échale un ojo [aquí](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files) sobre cómo añadir ficheros de datos a tu script.

Comment: ok gracias de todas formas lo intentaré pero como vez ya lo logré con tu recomendación de usar pyinstaller es mas fácil y rápido muchas gracias

Comment: está mejor mantenido. Py2exe, si vas a las [descargas](https://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/), parece que no se mantiene desde hace años y no hay versión para [tag:python3.x]. PyInstaller, sin embargo, [está más actualizado](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/) y funciona con Python hasta la versión 3.5. Otra opción para crear ejecutables para windows podría ser [pynsist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynsist) por si le quieres echar un ojo.

Comment: ok muchas gracias fue muy útil tu ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK lo hice con pyinstaller y funcionó perfecto y así lo hice en el cmd

```
C:\Carpeta\donde\este\ubicado\pyinstaller>pyinstaller.exe --onefile C:\Carpeta\donde\este\ubicado\tuprograma.py
```

fui a `C:\Carpeta\donde\este\ubicado\pyinstaller` y las tipicas carpetas `build` y `dist` las corté y las pegué en `C:\Carpeta\donde\este\ubicado\tuprograma.py` y abrí el exe perfectamente bien
(tienen que hacer el proceso de cortado y pegado ya que los complementos como imágenes, etc, siguen en la carpeta de `C:\Carpeta\donde\este\ubicado`\tuprograma.py de lo contrario no funcionará)